# RSYNC Filters Conflicting

Tags: rsync, filter

I've had to break my rsync tasks down into smaller jobs given the size of my directories.  Essentially, I'm doing it alphabetically (i.e., script that syncs folders starting with A-D, E-H, etc, etc).

The issue I'm having is this.....my A-D filter.txt file works fine, but all of the others fail.  I believe the issue is because the path that I'm syncing is:

```
/AUser/db/Backups/***
/AUser2/db/Backups/***
/CUser/db/Backups/***
/EUser/db/Backups/***
```

My filter.txt file for A-D looks like this:

```
- E*
- e*
- F*
- f* (etc all the way through Z)
+ */db/
+ */db/Backups/***
- *
```

The one above works with no issue.  However, this one does not:

```
- A*
- a*
- B*
- b* 
- C*
- c*
- D*
- d*
- I*
- i*
- J* (etc all the way through Z)
+ */db/
+ */db/Backups/***
- *
```

I'm guessing my exclusion of either d or B is causing this (it's excluding the db folder or the Backups folder??) but I can't figure out why since I have an include for */db/ and */db/Backups/***

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rsync filters work on the first match that is found - so yes, your excludes of "d*" and "B*" are excluding your "db" and "Backups" subdirectories before your include matches.

You'd be better off just including the specific paths you want included, and then excluding everything else, e.g.:

```
+ /[E-H]*            # include top-level dirs starting with E through to H
+ */db/              # include "db" subdirectories
+ */db/Backups/      # include "db/Backups" subdirectories
- */                 # exclude all other directories
```